# How do you read from a local SQLite file with .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I need to be able to read some data from a local SQLite DB file and I need the solution to work within the .NET Core 2.x framework - I'll be compiling this app cross-platform. So minimal dependencies is preferable!

Libraries I've looked at:

**Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core**

However on trying to use it I get the following error when I try to `Open()` a connection:

```
System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. 
(You need to call SQLitePCL.raw.SetProvider().  
If you are using a bundle package, this is done by calling SQLitePCL.Batteries.Init().)'
```

**System.Data.SqlClient**

Seems to have native stuff under it? IE hard to make cross platform.

Comment: You probably mean `System.Data.SQLite`; `System.Data.SqlClient` is for SQL Server (and that's fully supported on .NET Core). [EF Core supports SQLite](https://learn.microsoft.com/ef/core/get-started/netcore/new-db-sqlite).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came across the same error message earlier this week.

You should be using the **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite** package. 
It relies on **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core** as one of its dependencies so I imagine it handles some of the setup in the background.